# AWS PowerShell module - Get-RSCluster does not return Endpoint

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

When I execute Get-RSCluster | Select Endpoint the only thing returned is 'Amazon.Redshift.Model.Endpoint'. How am I able to use PowerShell to return the endpoint information for AWS Redshift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stumbling through AWS Tools right now and I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
$endpoint = Get-RSCluster -Select Endpoint
```

Fairly certain Amazon.Redshift.Model.Endpoint is a custom type with properties that can be accessed via dot. So in a PowerShell session after running the line above, you can run `$endpoint` on the next line to see what's contained in that object. Then you can do `$endpoint.whatever` to access those properties.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I didn't realize it was a custom type. Here's what I did: $endpoint = get-rscluster | select endpoint; $endpoint | select -expandproperty endpoint.